# Which setup script to use for setting up quartz sqlite table

Tags: quartz-scheduler

If i want to create quartz sqlite table with setup script provided by quartz 2.2.1, which setup script provided in database/tables folder of the Quartz should i use?

below is the list of setup script inside quartz database/tables:

[image]

quartz-2.2.1\docs\dbTables

Comment: or could it be quartz did not provide setup script for sqlite? i will wait for some answer. :)

Comment: I think you can go with the derby script and StdJdbcDriverDelegate (using an SQLite JDBC driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use derby script to be applied as my sqlite script

Comment: Don't you face any problem working with sqlite and quartz? See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779788/how-can-i-use-sqlite-in-quartz. I'm getting some errors when trying to retrieve job. The exception say: `org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve job: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver]`