# How can I use SQLite in Quartz?

Tags: java, sqlite, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to use quartz with SQLite in an application . When I read the documentation [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation) I notice that they didn't mention SQLite among the databases available. They say:

> JDBCJobStore works with nearly any database, it has been used widely
>   with Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MS SQLServer, HSQLDB, and DB2. To use
>   JDBCJobStore, you must first create a set of database tables for
>   Quartz to use. You can find table-creation SQL scripts in the
>   “docs/dbTables” directory of the Quartz distribution.

So, from this question: [Which setup script to use for setting up quartz sqlite table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483939/which-setup-script-to-use-for-setting-up-quartz-sqlite-table) I use derby script to be applied as my sqlite script.

The problem is when I trying to schedule a trigger in a previous inserted job. This is part of my code:

```
// and start it off
scheduler.start();

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", "value");

JobDataMap jdm = new JobDataMap(map);

JobKey key = new JobKey("job1", "key1");

 if(!scheduler.checkExists(key)){
     JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class).withIdentity(key).storeDurably().usingJobData(jdm).build();
     addJob(scheduler, job);

     // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 40 seconds
    Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
         .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
         .startNow()
            .forJob(job)
               .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                 .withIntervalInSeconds(40)
                 .repeatForever())            
         .build();

    // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
    scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger); // here is where I get an error
 }

Thread.sleep(60000);

scheduler.shutdown();
```

My quartz.properties is this:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.dataSource.SQLiteDB.driver = org.sqlite.JDBC
org.quartz.dataSource.SQLiteDB.URL = jdbc:sqlite:bota.db
org.quartz.dataSource.SQLiteDB.maxConnections = 30
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = SQLiteDB
```

I'm using sqlite v-3.8.11.2 and quartz v-2.2.2. This is what I get in the log:

```
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger 'group1.trigger1' for 'key1.job1' job:Couldn't retrieve job: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve job: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver]]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1223)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$4.executeVoid(JobStoreSupport.java:1159)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3715)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3713)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3799)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.executeInLock(JobStoreTX.java:93)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1155)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:932)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:258)
    at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:174)
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve job: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1396)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1205)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet.unused(JDBC4ResultSet.java:320)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet.getBlob(JDBC4ResultSet.java:345)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getBlob(NewProxyResultSet.java:285)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.getObjectFromBlob(StdJDBCDelegate.java:3190)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectJobDetail(StdJDBCDelegate.java:860)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1385)
    ... 10 more
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 11 seconds)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the sqlite jdbc driver [does not support the method ResultSet.getBlob()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.5-pre1/org/sqlite/jdbc4/JDBC4ResultSet.java).

But quartz uses this method to retrieve the [JobDataMap](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/index.html) that is assigned to a Job.

If you still want to use quartz with sqlite you could extend the [StdJDBCDelegate](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/index.html) and retrieve/set blobs like suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183783/java-sqlite-web-service-returning-blob).

At first glance it seems that you only must override the methods

1. StdJDBCDelegate.getObjectFromBlob() and
2. StdJDBCDelegate.getJobDataFromBlob()

Since I'm not sure wether later come more problems ( for example you could see that the sqlite jdbcdriver has a lot more [unsupported ResultSet methods](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.5-pre1/org/sqlite/jdbc4/JDBC4ResultSet.java) ) I would rather recommend to use a database which works out-of the-box.

Comment: Thanks @mam10eks, I just want to use an embedded database, so isn't compulsory use SQLite for me. Actually after that problem I started to looking for others embedded databases and decide to switch to H2.

Answer (score 2):

As per the suggestions of mam10eks, following code worked for me.

```
package com.example.quartz.sqlite;   

import org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class CustomJDBCDelegate extends StdJDBCDelegate {
  @Override
  protected Object getObjectFromBlob(ResultSet rs, String colName) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {
    byte[] bytes = rs.getBytes(colName);
    Object map = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
      bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
      ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
      map = ois.readObject();
    } catch (EOFException ex1) {
      bais.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // Error in de-serialization
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return map;
  }

  @Override
  protected Object getJobDataFromBlob(ResultSet rs, String colName) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {
    return getObjectFromBlob(rs, colName);
  }
}
```

Now put following in quartz.properties

```
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=com.example.quartz.sqlite.CustomJDBCDelegate
```